# How to remove ferric chloride stains?

Tags: pcb-fabrication

Okay, I know this might sound really offtopic. I made a PCB a while ago and got some ferric chloride stains in my clothes. I've been trying literally everything, from lemon juice, salt, vinegar, coke, bleach, sodium bicarbonate... 
I think it's really difficult to remove, but not impossible. 
Any advice I can get to save the clothes? 
Thanks!

Comment: Look at the trouble Pr. Clinton had (or was it Monica?).

Comment: The iron has likely bonded to the fabric. The methods of unbonding it will probably destroy the fabric itself.

Comment: @Andyaka It was the former Governor of Arkansas, not Tony Stark.

Comment: Let this be a lesson: don't use chemicals while wearing clothes you care about.  I bet you didn't have gloves or goggles either, right? :)

Comment: Are you cast **iron** sure about that **man** @Spehro?

Comment: Fire. Definitely fire. But I recommend changing out of the clothes first.

Comment: THe easiest way is to just buy PCBs made by professionals for cheap.

Comment: My white lab coat is far from white these days. It looks like I murdered someone a few years ago. I suggest you get one off eBay.

Comment: You can buy special ferric chloride cleaner that is supposed to get the stains out. I have never tried it so have no clue how good it is.

Answer (score 1):

I kind of doubt the stains will ever come out completely. Why don't you dye them in FeCl and make a fashion statement?

Some UK companies sell FeCl stain removal crystals, which appear to just be [Oxalic Acid](http://www.cdc.gov/niosh/ipcsneng/neng0529.html).

Comment: oxalic acid ... aka Cillit Bang.

Comment: Oxalic acid is also sold as deck cleaner in hardware stores. If it bleaches dyes or burns holes in your clothing...

Comment: @BrianDrummond, careful, saying the name of that product 3 times is said to cause Barry Scott to appear in your bathroom.  Nobody wants that.

Comment: Oxalic acid will remove iron, but not copper.   It is not good for clothes with snaps/rivets/zippers with iron content.